# How to host an ad hoc 802.11 network from Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, wifi, windows-10-iot-core

I want to allow my IoT device to receive a connection from a remote client without the device being connected to a wired network or a Wi-Fi access point. Bluetooth would be an obvious choice, but my clients might not have Bluetooth.

I thought WiFi Direct might be what I wanted but I see in the release notes for [Windows 10 IoT Core build 10586](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/ReleaseNotesRTM.htm) that

> WiFi Direct limitations on IoTCore
>
> 1.The IoTCore device has to be the connecting device – it will not work as the advertising device with another device initiating the connection.

This implies that API's like [WiFiDirectServiceAdvertiser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.services.wifidirectserviceadvertiser) are out and leaves me wondering what other options there are. If I want to do Wi-Fi it seems that I'll have to try to set up a non-WiFi Direct ad hoc Wi-Fi network. I can't find a .Net UWP API to do this ([WiFiAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter) seems to only facilitate connecting to networks that can be scanned for). Is there a way of achieving what I want, perhaps using a non-.Net API that is available on Windows 10 IoT Core?

Comment: I am curious how Visual Studio 2017 allows me to do do a WiFi search for my Raspberry Pi 3 and allow me to connect in order to deploy a build and do remote debugger over WiFi. This would seem to be the same functionality that you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a noob at Windows 10 IoT, but I have the same need.

I did notice that there's a way to [onboard a device using the IoT dashboard](https://blog.vjrantal.net/2016/03/24/headless-wifi-onboarding-of-windows-10-iot-core-devices/), which seems to connect your computer to the device via wifi in order to then join the device to a network.
So possibly there are some API's that can do a similar thing?